# Use Java to automate service creation and display up to date data on map?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, cartography, java, dynamic

Our team is using ArcGIS and our requirement is

1. To create a web application in JAVA with a map displaying various data from DB.
2. The data gets updated periodically in the DB  and the map should display it as and when the data is ready in DB.
3. Numerous fields of the DB should be selectable on the map on a demand basis.

Right now we are creating a mxd file and publishing it as service and showing it on the ArcGIS for Dexktop.

So I am pretty unsure if I should use the ArcGIS for Java SDK for all of my above requirements or go with ArcGIS for Javascript API.
Please let me know the best possible way to achieve this.

Comment: You seriously want to create the client side of the web application in JAVA? As in a Java Applet running in a browser? Just Don't Do It.

Comment: No by web application I mean creating UIs using JSPs, javascript, ajax. Is that not a good idea?

Comment: "ArcGIS for Java SDK" is slightly unclear. "ArcObjects Java" and "ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java" are for desktop applications. "Java Web ADF" is for web development, but it is deprecated in favor of the 3 current Web APIs: flex, silverlight and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Using JSP and ArcGIS javascript API with ArcGIS Server services / REST API is a fine combination. You can implement all the requirements that you've stated. With the js api, your server-side scripting language / framework becomes completely agnostic. FYI, if you need a nice interactive, sortable, searchable javascript data grid. Check out Data Tables -- it's jquery based and has good documentation. There is a also a plugin to export the table to a local csv file that I like. http://www.datatables.net/

Don't use the Java Web ADF -- it's deprecated!